# Инициация и инициирование проекта

Tags: употребление-слов

Добрый день!
В чем разница "инициация проекта" и "инициирование проекта"?

Answer (score 2):

Инициировать - это проявить первичную инциативу, дать чему-либо начало.

Инициация - это обряд перехода из одной ипостаси в другую. Примерами подобных обрядов будут: свадьба, выпускной, похороны.

Соответсвенно, проект можно инициировать (начать), а инициация проекта - это, наверное, обряд перехода проекта в реальное воплощение (если таковой существует, конечно).

Comment: Марк, спасибо.
Но мне нужен очень квалифицированный ответ.


Answer (score 1):

Инициирование проекта - это способствование его возникновению, слово из общепринятой лексики.

Инициация  проекта - это специальный термин. Инициация проекта (Project Initiating) – стадия процесса управления проектом, результатом которой является санкционирование начала проекта или очередной фазы его жизненного цикла. http://promanager.narod.ru/text/t3.pdf

Таким образом, инициирование - это начало деятельности, а инициация - это и начало, и дальнейшее развитие процесса.

Comment: София, этот пример я видела, разумеется. Но, исходя из него, инициирование является составной частью процесса инициации? Правильно?

Answer (score 0):

А как же быть с этим?

Грамота.ру
Здравствуйте!
Скажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли использовать слово "инициация" в значении "инициирование"?
Спасибо.
irina_k2
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Такая замена нежелательна

Comment: Согласно словарю, инициация - это религиозный обряд (слово относится к специальной лексике). В более широком значении это переход в новое качество или вхождение в новую группу.  Инициация проекта - это также термин, переход от идеи к ее воплощению, то есть переход в иное качество. А инициирование - это просто проявление инициативы в чем-либо, более общее понятие. Именно поэтому слово "инициация" не следует использовать по любому поводу, у этих слов разная область применения.